# Change background with an image stored in the iOS device on button's action

Tags: iphone, button, background, message

I'm developing a messaging app and I want to change the background image of the chat window on tapping the button (like Whatsapp) with an image stored in the device. Can anybody help me in writing code for that purpose?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a button, either from XIB/NIB or through code. On the action of that button, you need to change the background image of your view controller's view. Following code may be helpful for you.

```
-(void)changeBackgroundImage
{
    self.objImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
}
```

**objImageView** is the object of UIImageView on which you have to show the image.
**imageName.png** is the name of the image which you want to show on the UIImageView.

Comment: Thanks! It works me. But what I need is change the UIImageView with an image stored on the iPhone.

Comment: @Sergi Nameni Sempere What do you mean by "stored on the iPhone"? In iPhone Image Library or in your Resource Folder?